# How to Compile Custom Quickfix for python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to compile a custom quickfix for python3. I was wondering if anyone here knows how to do it? I cannot find any guides or tutorials to doing it. The only way I got it to work was installing a binary from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix

But Im not even sure how they created it and what modifications they used to get to this precompiled binary?